# Warning: Unknown option `hyperref' I dont' know the option `hyperref'

Tags: acro

Package acro Warning: Unknown option `hyperref' I dont' know the option` hyperref'. Please make sure there is no typo. Check the manual for help.

Hello! The same error come for "only-used". What can the error be?
I would be very thankfull for an answer

Comment: well you are doing something wrong, but you as you are not showing what you are doing, it is not really possible to tell you what.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please edit your post and add a complete code snippet that shows your problem. 'Complete' means that it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and when we compile it, it should show the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Before version 3 of the `acro` package, the package options could be given as arguments to `\usepackage`, such as `\usepackage[hyperref,only-used]{acro}`. This is a very common way of setting package options, but the package author opted to allow setting options only through the package-specific `\acsetup` command. The manual for version 2 already contained a deprecation warning:

> ACRO's package options are best set only via the setup command:
> `\acsetup{<options>}`
>
> They *might* work as package options to `\usepackage` as well but I do not recommend it and will likely remove this in a future version 3 of ACRO.

In the current version this has indeed been implemented. Therefore you should remove any options in `\usepackage` and use `\acsetup` instead.

Furthermore, the option `hyperref` is now called `make-links` and `only-used` is now called `list/display=used`.

Example code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{make-links=true}
\acsetup{list/display=used}
% alternatively: \acsetup{make-links,list/display=used}
[...]
```